# What is the correct way to link two classes to each other in Python

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I'm coding snake in python to practice.
So I have to classes: `Field()` and `Snake()`
I have to get attributes from `Snake` in `Field`
and also the other way around.

I do it like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  snake=Snake()
  field=Field(snake)
  snake.field = field
```

with the __ **init** __ in field:

```
def __init__(self, snake):
  self.snake = snake
```

Is this the "correct" way to do that or is there a better or more common way?

Comment: Why both need the other ? "The snake has some positons" i agree but why the other way

Comment: the "food" for the snake is made in field. And even when they wouldn't need each other I'd still wonder how I would do this in the case that they would need each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two classes must have references to one another, then a better way that would ensure this would be:

```
class Snake:
    def set_field(self, field):
        self.field = field


class Field:
    def __init__(self, snake):
        self.snake = snake
        snake.set_field(self)

snake = Snake()
field = Field(snake)
```

You now no longer explicitly have to code `snake.field = field` because now when you construct the `Field` object with an instance of a `Snake` object, the `Field` constructor will ensure that the `Snake` object is initialized with a reference back to the `Field` object. The point is that necessary initialization code should be placed in constructors, i.e. `__init__` methods, and since there is a relationship between `Field` and `Snake` that is bidirectional, make it explicit in the code.